# How to remove a custom style from the Normal.dotm template in MS Word?

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office

Not remove from the ribbon. I mean REMOVE. It's not a built-in style.

The following was suggested but didn't work: new document > Styles > Manage Styles > "edit" tab > (select the style) > click the button "new documents based on this template" > Delete > Confirm > OK > Save. (it's the only Word document open) > new document > Styles > It's still there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### If you want, you can use the Organizer to delete the style from your template.

*You do not have to actually open your existing template for editing, just modify it using the Organizer.*

Here is my writing about [the Organizer](https://www.addbalance.com/usersguide/styles.htm#Organizer) and [using the Organizer to delete styles](https://www.addbalance.com/usersguide/styles.htm#DeleteStylesOrganizer).

> [image: Organizer Dialog with steps to delete style]
>
> To get to the organizer in Word 2007 and later you can click on the
> Import/Export button on the Manage Styles Dialog Box (bottom left
> corner). (It is also  available on the Templates and Add-Ins dialog on
> the [Developer Tab](https://www.addbalance.com/word/developertab.htm).)
>
> [image: Manage Styles Dialog]
>
> **Word for the Mac**
>
> According to Word guru John Korchok, one way to access the Organizer
> on versions of Word for the Mac is:
>
> ```
> Choose Tools>Templates and Add-ins.
> Click on the Organizer button.
> ```
>
> This is similar to the methods in Windows.

When you close Word you should be asked if you want to save changes to the Normal template. Answer "Yes."

### You cannot delete any of the built-in styles.

You can modify them, you can hide most of them, you can remove them from the [Quick] Styles Gallery on the Home Tab, but you cannot delete them.

If these are your custom styles that you added to your Normal Template, then you can delete them using the Organizer or by direcly opening the Normal template and deleting them there. The Organizer is the preferred method.

When modifying directly in your document based on the template, be sure to check the option for "New documents based on this template."

This will only change things for new documents. Existing documents will still have the style unless you delete it in those documents directly.

While you should not need to do so, here is my writing on [how to open the Normal template in any version of Word](https://addbalance.com/word/normaltemplate.htm#Open). Make a backup before opening it.

**Additional Resources:**

- [What is the relationship in Word between a document and its template?](http://shaunakelly.com/word/templates/templaterelations.html) by Word MVP Shauna Kelly
- [Templates in Microsoft Word](https://www.addbalance.com/usersguide/templates.htm) (my page
- [Managing Word Styles](http://wordfaqs.ssbarnhill.com/ManageStyles.htm) by Word MVP Suzanne Barnhill
- [Understanding Styles in Microsoft Word](https://www.addbalance.com/usersguide/styles.htm) (my page)

Comment: It's not a built-in style. And I wrote in the question that I checked the "new documents etc" option. How do I delete a style?

Comment: I've added information about using the Organizer to delete the style from the Nomal template. including a link to the specific part on my Styles page about this. I reorganized the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You do this at your own risk. It worked when I tried it just now.

- Close Word.
- Find the file `Normal.dotm` and open it (it is likely to be in `C:\Users\<YourUserName>\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Templates`).
- Remove the style from that document.
- Save as and give it a different name, let's say `Normal2`, and save it as type "Word Macro-Enabled Template (*.dotm)".
- Close Word.
- Go into the directory you found Normal.dotm in
- Rename `Normal.dotm` to something like `Normal.dotm.old` so you have something to go back to if it goes wrong.
- Rename `Normal2.dotm` to `Normal.dotm`.

When you next open Word, the style is gone.

Warning: I don't know if it will break previous Word documents that used that style.

Comment: I upvoted because it's useful. But I wish there will be found a simpler solution. Thank you.